# Saving and retriving data using firebase and android

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

Am using firebase in android to add a message to a chat group then retrieve it back but when i press send it adds the new message and deletes the other child(ren) message(s) that were previously added so at any given instance i only remain with one message i.e the new message. any suggestions in fixing this.

capital talk and rush hour  are example of my groups (programname in the code) that i want to add messages as child(ren) with unique id generated by push and as you can see only a single message is retained
Setting up Firebase

```
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

                 mQuery = new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_URL+"/"+Constants.KEY_CHATS+"/"+programname);
                mQuery.orderByChild("timestamp").limitToLast(100);

        Adding new node
                final EditText ed_post = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_post);
                ImageButton btn_post = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_post);
                btn_post.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        String post = ed_post.getText().toString();
                        if (!post.isEmpty()) {
                            // chat.sendPost(post, program_id, station_id, user_id,



                            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());

                            Firebase chatbase =new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_URL+"/"+Constants.KEY_CHATS);
                            chatbase.child(programname).setValue(programname);

                            Firebase msgbaseref =new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_URL+"/"+Constants.KEY_CHATS+"/"+programname);
                            ChatsManager chm=new ChatsManager(username,post,timeStamp,"1",Constants.KEY_LIKES,Constants.KEY_COMMENTS);
                            msgbaseref.push().setValue(chm);




                            ed_post.setText("");
                            init();
                        }




        retrieving results/data to recycler view

            reycprogramlist.setHasFixedSize(true);
                mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
                reycprogramlist.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


                mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatsManager, ChatMessagesViewholder>(ChatsManager.class, R.layout.chat_list_item, ChatMessagesViewholder.class, mQuery) {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(ChatMessagesViewholder holder, ChatsManager item, int i) {

                        holder.tv_post.setText(item.getMessage());
                        holder.tv_time.setText(String.valueOf(item.getTimestamp()));
                        holder.tv_username.setText(String.valueOf(item.getUsername()));
                        // holder.tv_time.setText(String.valueOf(item.getTimestamp()));

                        if(username.equalsIgnoreCase(item.getUsername())){

                            holder.ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.right_chat);//iv_right.setImageBitmap(letterTile);

                        }else {

                            holder.ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.left_chat);//iv_right.setImageBitmap(letterTile);
                        }

                    }


                };





        ChatManager class
        public class ChatsManager {

            private String programname;
            private String username;
            private String message;
            private String timestamp;
            private String status;
            private String avatar;
            private String likes;
            private String comments;

            public ChatsManager(){}
            public ChatsManager(String username,String message, String timestamp, String status,String likes,String comments) {

                this.username = username;
                this.message = message;
                this.timestamp = timestamp;
                this.status = status;
                this.likes = likes;
                this.comments = comments;
            }

            public ChatsManager(String username){
                this.username = username;
            }

            public String getLikes() {
                return likes;
            }



            public String getComments() {
                return comments;
            }



            public String getProgramname() {
                return programname;
            }



            public String getUsername() {
                return username;
            }



            public String getMessage() {
                return message;
            }



            public String getTimestamp() {
                return timestamp;
            }



            public String getStatus() {
                return status;
            }



            public String getAvatar() {
                return avatar;
            }

        }



 Chats Json    
{
  "chats" : {
    "Breakfast Show" : {
      "ligaye" : {
        "comments" : "comments",
        "likes" : "likes",
        "message" : "ghhh",
        "status" : "1",
        "timestamp" : "2016.04.28.22.13.54",
        "username" : "ligaye"
      }
    },
    "Capital talk" : {
      "-KGStyEtP0GxxmDu99Gu" : {
        "comments" : "comments",
        "likes" : "likes",
        "message" : "kumeflood",
        "status" : "1",
        "timestamp" : "2016.04.28.20.25.58",
        "username" : "ligaye"
      }
    },
    "Capital talk2" : "Capital talk2",
    "Rush hour" : {
      "-KGDkn-PaKdnN3D9pFaX" : {
        "comments" : "comments",
        "likes" : "likes",
        "message" : "not working again",
        "status" : "1",
        "timestamp" : "2016.04.25.21.51.34",
        "username" : "ligaye"
      }
    }



    [This is how my chats structure looks like][1]


      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvHIX.png
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Seeing the code of where you are stuck would also go a long way. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i have added the code snippets

Comment: any help on this issue